# What does "if x in self:" mean?

Tags: python, class, contains

So I have a member method in Python with the following snippet:

```py
def foo(self, param):
    x = self._as_array(param)
    if x in self:
        raise KeyError('Data point {} is not unique'.format(x))
```

What does `if x in self:` mean here? It's not referencing any member method. E.g `if x in self._some_array` would make sense but merely stating `self` without any reference should mean what?

Comment: If `self` implements `__contains__`, then it can be used this way in a statement.  See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) in Python's Data Model.

Comment: self is class object and X contains the values of return function if _as_array(param). Now (if x in self:) condition is to identify whether whatever the value x contains is available under self.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x in y` is a Python language feature that relates to the `__contains__` method in the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__). Any class that implements that method can be used in such an expression.

```
x in y
```

is equivalent to

```
y.__contains__(x)
```

If `__contains__` is not implemented but the instance is iterable, Python will compare `x` to each value returned from an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

this is technicaly means you are asking the python to check weather the parameter x found in the object you passed.
one of the majic that the self can do is ,when ever you creat anobject it passes the object as  aprameter itself  ,so this means when you say self inside the function **init** you are are refering the object.

to understand this concept as well,you can take alook  the linked couse on
---->  [https://realpython.com/linked-lists-python/]
if you watch carefully how they iterate through the linked list ,they prifer to use
for node in self:
pass
than
while node:
pass
both the while loop ad the for loop work is the same way but ,the for is the fancy way to iterate through.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).